# Is there anything longer than unsigned long long int in C?

Tags: c

I'm using an unsigned long long int to store number of characters in a file. And I'm scared that its range will be bypassed soon. Is therr another datatype which can hold values more than unsigned long long int?

I also need 2 unsigned long long int arrays to store the pointers to certain positions in the file. However the maximum number of elements that I can have in an array is 10000. Is there a way to have a lot more?

Comment: goodness,, how big is your hard drive?

Comment: 10TB. And I'm reading values from a volume of 5 TB in Raw format. That is reading every character and storing them in a text file with both hex and char representation. Is it possible I'll overflow unsigned long long int with that much data?

Comment: heh well on my system, `unsigned long long` is 8 bytes, so that can hold values from 0 to 2^64-1. According to the answer, that's 18 exabytes. I don't know what an exabyte is, but it sounds big. A terabyte is 2^40, so 5 terabytes is 5*2^40.. that can easily fit in my `unsigned long long`. Although not necessary in this case, there are libraries available that deal with even larger numbers, googling can surely help you find some.

Comment: [18 exabytes is 18 *million* terabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes). If you have 18 million terabytes of data you need to store, you're gonna need a few billion dollars to afford that...

Comment: Updated the question a little. Can you kindly answer the next part as well?

Comment: Please keep your question focused to a single question. Open a new question if you have a new question. The two questions you're asking here aren't really related.

Comment: @Cornstalks: You can find 4 TB drives for about $100 on Amazon, so 18 EB would cost less than $0.5B (maybe quite a bit less if you get a bulk discount).  You can find 10 TB drives for about $320, too — but that's more expensive.  Of course, you also need to order a power station to get the electricity to run that much disk.

Comment: Unfortunately, the chances are here that **if you need to ask, you ain't gonna need it**

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also a mother board that has 70312 SATA ports.

Comment: Even if you manage to have a bigger data type, I am not sure how you will use it, since the standard file functions (`ftell`, `fseek`) work only with with `long int`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's true, but that's an oversimplified view. At 18 EB, you *will* see disk failures, so you need some level of replication (unless you're okay with partially corrupt data). So you need some extra disks. You also need computers/equipment to plug the disks into. And a physical building. And power. And cooling. And humans to put it all together (and maintain it). etc. You might be able to buy 18 EB worth of disks for under a billion dollars, but in order to actually use it I'm quite sure you'd have to blow through a few billion.

Comment: *"the maximum number of elements that I can have in an array is 10000"* - This seems to be a different question. You can have a lot more than 10,000 elements in an array. Unless you are declaring an array on stack. Maybe you need `malloc` to create array on heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the number of chars in a file you don't have to worry 
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=2%5E64+bytes+in+exabytes

That gives 18 exabyte files worth of storage space.

To answer the question directly though. You should look at a library of you need numbers larger that 64 bit

GMP is one I have used many times 
https://gmplib.org

As a note 
1 exabyte = 1,000,000 terabytes

Answer (score 3):

The largest standard integer type specified by the standard is `long long int`.

The [GCC 4.7.1 manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) says:

> ### 6.8 128-bits integers
>
> As an extension the integer scalar type `__int128` is supported for targets having an integer
>   mode wide enough to hold 128-bit. Simply write `__int128` for a signed 128-bit integer, or
>   `unsigned __int128` for an unsigned 128-bit integer. There is no support in GCC to express
>   an integer constant of type `__int128` for targets having `long long` integer with less then [*sic*]
>   128 bit width.

One of such types is `__int128`, which is available on `x86-64` and supported by all major compilers. As you can guess, it's 128 bits wide.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using an unsigned long long int to store number of characters in a file.

Most of the file systems nowadays also use 64 bits to store the file size (e.g with ext2, it's `i_size` + `i_dir_acl`, two 32 bits integers).

With 64 bits, the maximum file size is 18 exabytes, which is very, very big.